# Space Invaders With 2 Errors Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with increasing the score in my space invaders clone. I have 2 errors.

> Assets/Scripts/ScoreManager.cs(26,12): error CS0103: The name
>   `retryLevel' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets/Scripts/ScoreManager.cs(55,43): error CS1061: Type `int' does
>   not contain a definition for`Tostring' and no extension method
>   `Tostring' of type`int' could be found. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference?

Where and what exactly in my script should I change?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{

int i = 0;
public GameObject HighScoreDisplay;
public Text scoreDisplay;
public int score = 0;
public Text[] highScoreTables;


private void Start()
{
  if (HighScoreDisplay == null || scoreDisplay == null)    {

            Debug.LogWarning("Values are missing on the ScoreManager!");

            return;

        }

           retryLevel();

}

private void update()
{
  scoreDisplay.text = score.ToString();

}

public void ModifyScore(int scoreToAdd)
{
  score += scoreToAdd;

}

public void fromScratch(){
  score = 0;
  HighScoreDisplay.SetActive(false);
}

public void PlayerDied()
{


  HighScores.AddScore(score);

  foreach (Text table in highScoreTables)
  {
    table.text = HighScores.scoreTable[i].Tostring();

    i++;
  }

  HighScoreDisplay.SetActive(true);
  score = 0;

}

}

public static class HighScores


{

  public static List<int> scoreTable = new List<int>{0,0,0};

  public static void AddScore(int score)
{
  if (score > scoreTable[2])
  {
    scoreTable[2] = score;
  }
  else if (score > scoreTable[1])
{
  scoreTable[1] = score;
}
else if (score > scoreTable[0])
{
scoreTable[0] = score;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors are simple:

1. your code does not contain definition for function `retryLevel` nor do I see any static using to be available for importing such a function from other class, *(It is a inherited function from `MonoBehaviour`? Are you sure it has not uppercase first letter according to C# standards?)*
2. you have `Tostring` with small `S`. It should be `ToString`.

Comment: `retryLevel` is not inherited from `MonoBehaviour`, which is a Unity class with full documentation.

Comment: I suspected already this much. *(Unfortunately I'm not a Unity developer and I was too lazy to read the documentation. Instead I finished my own project.)* It still could be a extension. But the probability is low.